# RealityKit Changing Material After the Collision

Tags: augmented-reality, realitykit

I am using the following code to detect collision between two model entities. The event does get fired and change the material of one of the entities. For some reason the material for both entities (entityA and entityB) is being changed.

// add collision begin subscriptions
self?.collisionSubscriptions.append(arView.scene.subscribe(to: CollisionEvents.Began.self) { event in

```
                print(event.entityA)
                print(event.entityB)
                
                guard let entity = event.entityB as? ModelEntity else { return }
                entity.model?.materials = [SimpleMaterial(color: .green, isMetallic: true)]
                
               
            })
```

Any ideas why this is happening?